# How to reverse 'url' of included urls in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Suppose my projects `urls.py` looks something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("foo/", include("foo.urls"), name="foo"),
]
```

Then I have a file `foo/urls.py`, that has some further urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("bar/", views.bar, name="bar"),
    path("baz/", views.baz, name="baz"),
]
```

#### What I would like to do

Get the 'partial' url that takes you so far as the included 'urls'. For example, I could do `reverse("bar")` to get `foo/bar`. But I can't seem to do `reverse('foo') to get just` foo`. Is there a way of doing this.

#### One (unideal) solution

I could put a dummy view inside `foo/urls.py` right at the very end with a path of `""`, and then reverse this. However I don't like this solution. It feels hacky, and would potentially have problems if a user ever hit this URL.

Comment: Might I suggested including a namespace in your foo `include` call. This will make for nicer url reversal and allow you to use multiple urls with the same name as long as the namespace is different.

Answer (score 1):

Your unideal solution is actually exactly how it would be intended in Django. That means adding a path in `foo.urls`: `path("", views.index, name="foo")`.

I understand that this feels hacky to you, but currently the /foo path refers to no resource on your server, as no path for it has been defined. It would make no sense for Django to ever even be able to reverse this path, as it points to nothing.

If you still want to reverse the path, while Django would return a 404 error, you would actually have to define a simple view returning a 404 response.

Comment: What if the included urls come from a third party library?